# HTTP Post request from PHP to NodeJs Server

Tags: php, node.js, post, http-post

I tried to make a request to my nodeJS using CURL from PHP.
Here is my code:

```
$host = 'http://my_ip:8080/ping';
$json = '{"id":"13"}';

$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
    );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
```

But it doesn't work. I received bool(FALSE) in data var.

NodeJS:

```
app.use(router(app));
app.post('/ping', bodyParser, ping);
port = 8080;
app.listen(port, webStatus(+port));
function* ping() {
    console.log(this.request.body);
    this.body = 1;
}
```

I tried with NodeJS Http-post and it works:

```
http.post = require('http-post');
http.post('http://my_ip:8080/ping', { id: '13' }, function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```

Is it something wrong with PHP code?

PS: The CURL is included in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ping` function is not well implemented I think.

Also, you need to call the `send` method in order to send the HTTP response.

You should declare the function like this :

```
app.use(bodyParser); // You can use a middleware like this too.

app.post('/ping', ping);

function ping (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // Since you use `bodyParser` middleware, you can get the `body` directly.

    // Do your stuff here.

    res.status(200).send('toto');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but was not that. My webhost restricting http-post on this port, with nodejs is working well because was installed on my laptop, but my php project is hosted, i change port in 88 and it's work well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to know that you fixed your problem :)